# After created a prefab when dragging the prefab back to the hierarchy there are 3 missing scripts on two objects how can I solve it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using : Unity 2019.2.5f1 Personal

I have some gameobjects some of them are prefabs under one general parent gameobject.
Then I dragged the parent gameobject to the assets and created a new prefab.

Since then when I drag the prefab to the hierarchy on two objects Player and Player Camera there are missing scripts. But it's not that there are missing scripts since all scripts in places it's like a bug or something that add the missing scripts but there should no any more scripts.

[image: Missing script]

But there was no any script there that now is missing I can't figure out where is this missing script is came from.

I tried to open the prefab in the assets and to remove the "missing" scripts then I tried to drag the prefab to the hierarchy removed the "missing" scripts and then did Overrides > Apply All

But still it didn't change. Still when dragging the prefab to the hierarchy it's showing this missing scripts. One missing script on the Player and two others on the Player Camera.

Comment: You're the only person who has any knowledge of what scripts those were.

Comment: If you remember which scripts these are then on the prefab drag them from the `Assets` into the `Script 
 Missing (Mono Script)` field. And we'll .. are there any compiler errors? Did you rename a file or class? -> Note that the `MonoBehaviour` class name has to match exactly the script file name e.g. `public class Example : MonoBehaviour {}` **has to** be called `Example.cs` (the `.cs` is not visible in the UnityEditor but in the system's Filebrowser)

Comment: If the .meta files are still in the trash bin of your OS you have a chance. Recover them from there into a tmp folder. Then open the affected prefab file in a text editor and try to figure out the guid of the missing script maybe by doing it step by step. You do this by looking for entries like _m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: 2dc165eb1dde48409df5d63f1ed19541, type: 3}_ . Then do a full text search for the guid on your tmp folder